# How to make a page in read only for a current User

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

My question is how to make a page in read only for the current user using Javascript.
something like this:

```
function function() {
    var userId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
    var owner= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ownerid").getValue();
    var ownerID = owner[0].id;

    // if user#owner
    if (userId != ownerID) {
        //make a current user in readonly
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea?

thank you in advance

Comment: Please add details and explanation in your question. Also show what you tried and why it is not working for you. [See how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
function onLoad() {
    var userId = Xrm.Page.context.getUserId();
    var owner= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ownerid").getValue();
    var ownerId = owner[0].id;

    if (userId != ownerId) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.forEach(function (control) {
            control.setDisabled(true);
        });
    }
}
```

But, if your requirement is only to prevent users from updating records they do not own, it is better to set their Write-privilege for the entity to User level.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean that you want the current page not to be interactive with user, then you can do something like this in javascript:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);"></div>';
```

This will make the page grayed and disabled for user interaction.